# Single-sign-on in DMZ / OpenLDAP

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, openldap, dmz

we have a dmz with several https-based services, which users from internal network use although as users from outside.
To ensure authentification with the active directory user-credentials, we set up an OpenLDAP server in the dmz, which
gets its Information from the Active-Directory-Domaincontrollers from the internal network.

For user convenience, we want to get single-sign-on-functionality, too, for our services. Is this possible
and what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For single sign on, try using OKTA. It's easy to integrate your application into okta. There are many tutorials out there for okta. But remember it is a paid service.

Reference : [OKTA](https://www.okta.com/)